# What kind of database should I use?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm a graphic designer and a beginning web developer. I currently created a simple site with an input form. Now I want to link each user's input to either answer "A" or "B"

For example, if a user types "1" and presses submit, the answer "1 is A" or "1 is B" will show up. I need to do this for approximately 55000 instances, all wich have either answer "A" or "B". What kind of database do you recommend I should use? Or can this be done through PhP or SQL? I'm absolutely clueless how this works, but would like a good starting point.

Comment: Every database can handle that tiny bit of data.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, would you mind explaining your requirement a bit. And regarding which DB to use, you can use any, preferably PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of PHP and mysql.

Step 1. create site that will get for you current user. [ using db or session ]

Step 2. create simple form. [ that will get you needed data from users ]

Step 3. create 3xmysql tables, user, user_answers, question. [ in user answer you will collect userId / QuestionId / answer [b, a, c, d or smth];

Step 4. create mysqli/pdo connection.

Step 5. test and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Databases usually have a file size limit, or licence limit. If you are purchasing a hosting service, check the databases available for use, and post those limits here.

So far your question is too broad.

Most databases are very powerfull, and will deal with thousands or millions of datas, without using over a couple seconds of processing.

PHP and MySQL tend to be easier to use (from my perspective and experience), are free, and have 2 gigabytes limits (for free versions). I suggest looking at those first.